# How to fetch keys from key vault of azure using share access signature?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

How I can use shared access signature to fetch keys from key vault of azure storage.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Key Vault only supports Azure Active Directory-based authentication, not SAS keys. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault#data-plane-access-control